# Error Store Address Not Aligned on Word Boundary MIPS

Tags: assembly, memory, mips, store, cpu-architecture

**There is an error on line 54 and not sure how to fix it,**

**Line 54 has the code "sw  $t0, ($s2)  #Store $s2 (the second integer) in buf[$s0]."**

**Error on Line 54: Runtime exception at 0x00400028: store address not aligned on word boundary 0x00000002**

**I am also wondering if my code is right?**

**I am using the following procedure for this code.**

---

**Consider buffer ‘buf’ as an array of words. The first integer you read ($s0) is an index into the array (since ‘buf’ has only 128 bytes, the first integer must be between 0 and 31). Store $s2, the second integer you read in step 10, into buf[$s0]. The steps you need to perform include:**

Load the starting address of ‘buf’ into $t0.

Calculate the offset of word buf[$s0] (i.e., 4 times the value in $s0).

Calculate the address of buf[$s0].

Store $s2 (the second integer) in buf[$s0].

**Print out the following information:**

Value $s0 (the first integer) in decimal (system call 1).

New line string (at location ‘newline’).

Load the address of buf[$s0] to $s1

Value $s1 (the address) in hexadecimal (system call 34).

New line string (at location ‘newline’).

Value $s2 (the second integer) in hexadecimal.

```
    .data               #data segment
newline:    .asciiz "\n"            #ASCII for a new line. asciiz with z means 0 (not character '0') is placed after the last character. 
.align 2            # The next variable (symbol) should starts at an address that is a multiple of 4.
name:   .asciiz "CSE3666: Lab 0: YOUR NAME \n\n\n"
.align 2
msg1:   .asciiz "\nThe first integer you just typed is\n"
.align 2    
buf:    .space 128          # Reserve space for a variable (array). Not 
initialized.

.align 2
reserved:   .space 20       

.text               # Code segment
.globl  main            # declare main to be global

main:   
# load an address, which is a 32-bit value. 
# Could be a symbol. See the example below. Still, the value is a 32-bit 
value.
# la is a pseudo instruction.It is converted into two instructions.
#la $a0, 0xBF63C886         

# Load a large constant with two instructions. Higher 16 bits will be 0 
although the MSB of the constant is 1.
#lui    $a0, 0xBF63     
#ori    $a0, 0xC886 

# example of subtraction
#sub    $a0, $a0, 1

# read user inputted integer
li  $v0, 5
syscall
# store the integer into $s0
move    $s0, $v0

# read user inputted integer
li  $v0, 5
syscall
# store the integer into $s2
move    $s2, $v0

#store $s0 to buf[$s0]
#address = base + index * 4
#          la     sll $s0 by 2
#la
#sll
#add
#sw
la  $t0, buf    #Load the starting address of ‘buf’ into $t0.
sll $s0, $s0, 2 #Calculate the offset of word buf[$s0] (i.e., 4 times the 
value in $s0).
add $t0, $t0, $s0   #Calculate the address of buf[$s0].
sw  $t0, ($s2)  #Store $s2 (the second integer) in buf[$s0].

la  $a0, msg1   #print message
li  $v0, 4
syscall

lw  $t0, buf    
li  $v0, 1      # system call, type 1, print an integer, *$a0
syscall         # call the "OS"

la  $a0, newline    #new line
li  $v0, 4
syscall

lw  $t0, ($s1)  #Value $s1 (the address) in hexadecimal 
li  $v0, 34     
syscall

la  $a0, newline    #new line
li  $v0, 4
syscall

lw  $t0, ($s2)  #Value $s2 (the second integer) in hexadecimal.
li  $v0, 34
syscall

Exit:   li  $v0,10      # System call, type 10, standard exit
syscall
```

Comment: `sw  $t0, ($s2)  #Store $s2 (the second integer) in buf[$s0].` you got operands switched. Should be `sw $s2, ($t0)`.

Comment: Although it looks like this assembler goes, right to left. Could it be "sw ($t0), $s2 ?

Comment: @user3344003: Both `lw` and `sw` have the address as the second operand in MIPS assembly.